# How to connect my custom block to the layout

Tags: module, theme, custom-block

So there's one piece of the custom block puzzle I'm not really getting.

What I'm trying to do:

I want to use *$this->getChildHtml('customBlock')* inside my *header.phtml* file and have it just print 'Hello World'

What I have thusfar:

An xml file called *app/etc/modules/* **Jiri_CustomBlock.xml** with the following contents:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
     <modules>
        <Jiri_CustomBlock>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Jiri_CustomBlock>
     </modules>
 </config>
```

Then a file called *app/code/local/Jiri/CustomBlock/etc/* **config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
     <modules>
         <Jiri_CustomBlock>
             <version>0.0.1</version>
         </Jiri_CustomBlock>
     </modules>
 </config>
```

This works, I can go to *System>Configuration>Advanced* and see it inside the Disabled Modules Output

Then I have this in *app/code/local/Jiri/CustomBlock/Block/* **Header.php**

```
 class Jiri_CustomBlock_Block_Header extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header{
      public function helloWorld(){
          return 'Hello World';
      }
 }
```

Lastly I have this in my custom theme folder in *app/design/frontend/customtheme/default/template/page/html/* **customblock.phtml**

```
 <?php echo $this->helloWorld(); ?>
```

Now for the million dollar question; how do I make it so this custom local module/block becomes a child block of the header block?

I have this thusfar in my **local.xml** but I have no idea how to connect the code to this part.

```
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="(what do I add here?)" template="page/html_header">
        </block>
    </reference> -->
```

I looked around online and I found out I can add 'company/module' in the 'type' attribute, but then how does it know to load Block/Header.php?

Comment: Is that the complete contents of `config.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the below changes to your code,

In config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config>
         <modules>
             <Jiri_CustomBlock>
                 <version>0.0.1</version>
             </Jiri_CustomBlock>
         </modules>
        <global>
          <blocks>
             <jiri_customblock>
                <class>Jiri_CustomBlock_Header</class>
              </jiri_customblock>
          </blocks>
        </global>
     </config>
```

In local.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="jiri_customblock/header" name="customBlock" as="customBlock" template="page/html/customblock.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in `etc/config.xml` add block in `<global>` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
     <modules>
         <Jiri_CustomBlock>
             <version>0.0.1</version>
         </Jiri_CustomBlock>
     </modules>
<global>
<blocks>
      <jiri_customblock>
        <class>Jiri_CustomBlock_Block</class>
      </jiri_customblock>
    </blocks>

</global>
 </config>
```

in `local.xml`  add `name` of block

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="jiri_customblock/header" name="html_header" template="page/html_header" >
            </block>
</reference>
```